# Redirect_to in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

For example I have a controller PostController in RoR 4. and actions in it:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
end

def new
    @post = Post.new #second question
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    post.save
    redirect_to @post #first question
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
```

so, the first question is: Why when we write `redirect_to @post` it automatically redirect to `show/id`? How rails know, that it must go to `show` view?

second question: why I must write `@post = Post.new` in new action? when I comment it, I also can create a `Post`. What is the deference write it in `new` action or missing it?

I'm new in rails and there are many magic in it

Comment: can you share full content of PostController please?

Comment: Hey @Jack Daniel. It appears that my answer introduced some confusion. Would you mind updating your question, and add the templates (both of `new` view, and of your form - in case you moved it to separate partial)? I'd like to update my answer accordingly to omit any confusion in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1). This is part of one of main RoR's mantras - convention over configuration. It just assumes, when performing `redirect_to @post`, you actually want to see the `@post` resource. The standard REST action of "reading" the resource is `show`.

But, if - for example - in your view you will do something like

```
<%= link_to @post.title, @post, method: :delete %>
```

What will be generated by that will take you to `destroy` action of `@post`'s resource.

Having conventions like this make you write less code, and - make you happy!

Q2). I'm surprised if what you mentioned worked. It shouldn't, because similar magic is performed in your `form_for @post` tag in your views. If `@post` is empty, `form_for` shouldn't be able to resolve what url to generate, or how to behave in general - depending on `Post.new` stored in `@post` it assumes you want to `create` the resource, and prepare your `<form>` tag to submit with `POST` method, but if in `@post` there is stored already persisted resource, say `Post.find(1)`, it will create the `<form>` to be submitted with `PATCH` method.

Again - based on convention, you can write less code, to achieve more.

*I strongly advise against **omitting** something like `@post = Post.new`. It may lead to hard to identify bugs, even if it worked for you at the moment*

Hope it clarifies things!

Good luck!

Comment: tnx for great and detailed answer. I got it.

Comment: your second answer is not correct. The form does not need @post to submit a valid post, it just uses it as a place to put the errors if the submission is invalid. The new page will work completely fine as long as you don't need to display the errors.

Comment: Let me check it - I'll do some tests across coupe versions of Rails, and I'll update my answer. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Hey @RailsOuter! I tried to create simple app, and scaffolded simple `Product` . When I commented out `@product = Product.new` in my `ProductsController#new`, the application failed on that action with error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`. This is when in view I still have `<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>`. On the other hand, when I convert the `form_tag` in the view the following way (I deleted @product) - `<%= form_for do |f| %>`, the error thrown is `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)`. Would you mind providing example code for your case? I tested for Rails 4.2

Comment: @Pawel Dawczak ,That's because you are using `form_for @product`, which is not the only way to do it. You can say `form_for :product, url: products_path do` , and it will work, we didn't use the `@product`, now go ahead and delete it from your controller, the view will complain about the errors only, if you remove the lines that correspond to the error display in your form, it will work just fine. Conclusion : You don't need `@post` in the new action if you are not going to display errors.

Comment: Hey @RailsOuter! Thanks for clarification, now I see your point! Because there multiple ways of using `form_for`, and the question was about "how does Rails magic work", I assumed, that we're dealing with the most "magical" example of using `form_for`. Just to be clear - **I have never suggested** in my answer that `form_for @post` is *the only way* to proceed with forms. I think it's worth putting an example of "problematic" template to the question, so it is clear what exactly we work with. I'll put all my effort to update the answer to omit any *confusion*. Again - thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

First questions: it redirects you to the show page using the `url_for` method (you can read its source if you are curious), remember that @book has an id so it takes that id and includes it in the url of the `/books/:id`

Second question : you need @post for when you submit an invalid form, then @post will be populated with the errors and displayed on the `new` page. try to submit an invalid post, you will get complains about a not defined method.

to display the errors of an invalid submission :

```
<%= form_for :post posts_path do |f| %>

  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
```

See how we used @post above? just to get the errors in it.

Answer (score 1):

When passing a record to `redirect_to` the url will be generated by calling `url_for`, which will return a named url for that record. For this it uses the class name for lookup. So passing the Post record will attempt to use the `post_path` route with the original record as parameter which will resolve in `/posts/:id`.

Answer (score 0):

**First question**

Rails magic.

As you pass an ActiveRecord object to redirect, the restful routing interprets this as you wanting to go to the show page of that object.

Plenty of different ways to use redirect_to [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to).

**Second question**

Usually `@post = Post.new` is required as you reference `@post` in the new action as your forms when constructed with `form_for` .. useful for validation and dealing with errors.

Technically you could use a `form_tag` and define `Post.new` right there in the form. This would mean the `@post = Post.new` is redundant and works when you comment it out. This way would mean you have no way to pass your objects errors back to the user on the new page though.